# How to deploy a web service on a server machine?

Tags: java, web-services

I have developed a web service in Java which needs to be deployed on a dedicated server. I have deployed the service on my machine and it works fine. Now, I want to deploy in a long-running server machine. How can I deploy the web service so that it is a long running server process? I prefer to deploy it on Tomcat.

**PS** : I have developed the web service in Eclipse and my os is windows 7.

Comment: I don't understand *How can I deploy the web service so that it is a long running server process?* Are you using Tomcat/Jetty?

Comment: Install Tomcat on the server you want to deploy your webservice to, start it when the server is booted and deploy your application that contains the webserver to it. Job done.

Comment: Download Tomcat in the machine, add your `war` in webapps Tomcat directory, run Tomcat by `{tomcat_dir}/bin/catalina.sh run`. Done.

Answer (score 1):

The way to have a Java program started when the computer boots is to install it as a service.  Several options exist for wrapping a Java program with the necessary magic to do this.  I have had good experience with the "winsw" by Kohsuke of Jenkins fame.

https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw

You will need to have administrator access and you will benefit from reading up on how Windows work with services to understand why you cannot see swing windows and run jvisualvm etc.

Comment: Note that Tomcat knows how to install itself as a service if you have a WAR file.